# 1's complement to 2's complement conversion

Tags: java, twos-complement, ones-complement

My code is a class for converting decimal to binary. it will display the binary, one's complement and two's complement. So far I have figured out the one's complement but having a problem finding a solution for the two's complement. my plan was to use the output of the ones complement as an input to the two's complement method and convert there. Is this the right approach?

```
//This method will convert binary result to ones complement
public String do1sComp(){
    if (binaryValue.length() == 0)
        doBinary();

    //Ones Complement
    char[] digits = binaryValue.toCharArray();
    for (char digit : digits){
        if(digit == '0'){
            onesComp += "1";
        }
        else 
            onesComp += "0";
        }

    return onesComp;
}

/* This was my attempt to start the method
public String do2sComp(){
    if (onesComp.length() == 0){
        if (binaryValue.length() == 0)
            doBinary();

        do1sComp();
    }

    //Twos Complement


} */
}
```

Comment: To get the 2's complement, take the 1's complement and add one.

Comment: Where would I add the 1?

Comment: You'd add it to the low-order bit, then ripple-carry up the line as required.  Just like you'd add 1 to any number.

Comment: Initial number `01010100`, 1's complement `10101011`.  Add 1 = `10101100`.  (An interesting attribute of a binary number and it's 2's complement is that both will have the same number of right-hand zeros.)

Comment: (And you can isolate the least-significant 1 in a binary number by ANDing the number with it's 2's complement.)

Comment: @tms777: You're aware `Integer.toBinaryString` exists, right?

Comment: I'm new to programming. Not familiar with that but am interested in how it can be implemented. Been looking it over and it seems to be what I looking for, just need a little help getting it going.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2's complement is just adding a `1` to the 1's complement. Now, you are adding a binary bit 1 and not an `int` 1.

You will be storing the 2's complement in an `int`. Just add another `int` that contains binary 1. Getting two's complement is a little bit more involved. This involves bitwise addition. However, there is a trick to it that I had learned in highschool.

Consider the number six in binary as `0110`. The one's complement is `1001`. The two's complement is `1010`. The trick is this, find the right-most one. Having done that, flip the bits to the left of it, all the way to the end.

Use `Integer.toBinaryString()` to see your answer.

To store a bit 1 in an `int`, you'd do `int bit = 0b0001` This will store a bit 1 in the lower-order bits of the int.

*PS: I haven't made an SSCCE. Please correct me if I am wrong*

Comment: would return Integer.toBinaryString(dotwosComp); work?

Comment: @tms777 `Integer.toBinaryString()` takes in an `int` and gives back its binary representation. What are you trying to achieve ? =)

Comment: I would like to convert the 1s comp into 2s comp and return that value

Comment: Please update me when you are done. I'd genuinely love to know if I was of any help =)

Comment: No problem. Will have this finished by the morning. Once everything is running I will post the result.